# list tags with count in author profile page

Tags: functions, wp-query, tags

I would like to list tags with count in author profile page just like [this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/5074/giri?tab=tags)

If the user click the tag, then I would like to list the tagged posts.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function get_author_post_tags_wpa78489($author_id,$taxonomy = 'post_tag'){
    //get author's posts
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'author' => $author_id,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
        )
    );

    $ts = array();

    //loop over the post and count the tags
    foreach ((array)$posts as $p_id) {
        $tags = wp_get_post_terms( $p_id, $taxonomy);
        foreach ((array)$tags as $tag) {
            if (isset($tags[$tag->term_id])){ //if its already set just increment the count
                $ts[$tag->term_id]['count'] = $ts[$tag->term_id]['count']  + 1;
            }else{ //set the term name start the count
                $ts[$tag->term_id] = array('count' => 1, 'name' => $tag->name, 'slug' => $tag->slug);
            }
        }
    }

    //so now $ts holds a list of arrays which each hold the name and the count of posts 
    //that author have in that term/tag, so we just need to display it
    $url = get_author_posts_url($author_id);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($ts as $term_id => $term_args) {
        echo '<li><span class="count">'.$term_args['count'].'</span> <a href="'.add_query_arg('tag',$term_args['slug'],$url).'">'.$term_args['name'].'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to list the tagged post url when the user click the tag link?. As of now it doesn't show post url

Comment: Also please fix the closing ul tag.

Comment: Fixed, are you getting the posts? its working on my end, see (`.add_query_arg('tag',$term_args['slug'],$url)`)

Comment: No, I'm not getting the posts. When I click the tag it looks like this `http://example.com/author/authorusername?tag=tagname`. But I'm not seeing any posts. Is that function should be placed within the loop?

Comment: place it anywhere you want!, what you permalink?

Comment: Yes I changed my author base from `author` to `user` to user. Is that a problem?

Comment: This is weird. Yesterday it didn't work. Now its working. Thankyou